# Android app does not work on Tablet

Tags: android, layout, tablet

I have created an android application, that doesn't run on Tablet.

I have added `xml` files in `res/layout-large` folder. When I run on emulator it's working but in Tablet it gives error like-  `Unfortunately xxx has stopped.`

**Logcat** output:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{idev.android.soulspotter/idev.android.soulspotter.Login}:
> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f030021
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030022
> at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1018)
> at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2105)
> at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:857)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
> at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
> at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1862)
> at idev.android.soulspotter.Login.onCreate(Login.java:57)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4492)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
> ... 11 more

Please give me solution.

Comment: Please post you logcat.

Comment: Full LogCat needed to support you.

Comment: what is `line no 57` in `Login` class

Comment: This is line no 57-  `setContentView(R.layout.login_large);`

Comment: @SagarZala : what is the `xml's name` of ur `res/layout` folder

Comment: @kaushik : login_large.xml

Comment: @kaushik, When I run on emulator it's working proper but in Tablet it gives error.

Comment: check in both layout folder the xml name is same

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47322/discussion-between-kaushik-and-sagar-zala)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the xml files in same folder "Layout"

May be it work.

Answer (score 0):

Check all objects in your view - its position on the screen and dependency of other objects made in the same view.
I had same situation and after changing its position all aplication works properly .

Comment: I tried, but it works only on emulator not on tablet.

Comment: Maybe  just crete your view in res/ layout (like for mobile phone size  display)

Answer (score 0):

1.in eclipse, go to Project > Clean… 2.select your project, then press OK 3.relaunch the app

if it happens again delete the r.java file. it will generate automatically.

ANd check names in all resources are matching and not capital letter. Also check your manifest

```
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
  android:normalScreens="true" 
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:xlargeScreens="true"
  android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: I tried, but it works only on emulator not on tablet.

Comment: how can this be a solution to what op asked

Answer (score 0):

I put all the xml files in res/layout and my work is done.